# Xdebug not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

Xdebug does not stop at breakpoints.

I tried different versions of Xdebug. (current v1.32.1, v1.32.0,  v1.31.1, v1.31.0, v1.30.0)

This is my configuration at the `launch.json` file:

```json
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 0,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
        ],
        "env": {
            "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
            "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
            "-S",
            "localhost:0"
        ],
        "program": "",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 9003,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
            "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
            "action": "openExternally"
        }
    }
]}
```

Could there be a conflict with the web server?

This is my configuration in the `php.ini` (all the way at the bottom of the file):

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003        // it also doesnt work without this line.
```

Installation Wizard

```text
Summary from <https://xdebug.org/wizard> 

    • Xdebug installed: 3.2.1
    • Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
    • Windows: yes 
    • Compiler: MS VS16
    • Architecture: x64
    • Zend Server: no 
    • PHP Version: 8.2.4
    • Zend API nr: 420220829
    • PHP API nr: 20220829
    • Debug Build: no
    • Thread Safe Build: yes
    • OPcache Loaded: no
    • Configuration File Path: no value
    • Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    • Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've downloaded the file from the wizard and renamed it correctly.

Port 9003 is correct according to the documentation. But I also tried port 9000 as well.

If I go to https://portchecker.co/checking and check for Port 9000 or 9003 they are closed.

- I reinstalled XAMPP
- I reinstalled VS Code

I also went to `Settings -> Features -> Debug -> Allow Breakpoints Everywhere`.

Comment: You mention you've tried versions "1.32.1, v1.32.0, v1.31.1, v1.31.0, v1.30.0", but your later output refers to the much more likely "3.2.1". Where did you see those other version numbers?

Comment: I get these version Numbers by installing it in VS Code.
Here i can also change to an older version.
Now that i think about it this must be the version of the VS Code Plugin and not of xDebug.
My xDebug version is shown by the Installation Wizard Summary:
Xdebug installed: 3.2.1

Now I´m not shure how to get to an older version of xDebug.
I have to keep looking.

Comment: dexhowl founld a mistake i made at copying the code.
In my php.ini file there is no apostrophe  at [xdebug]`
it is just [xdebug]
thx for looking that close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and installed xampp and xdebug.

Our launch.json files and wizard output are identical and it seems to work ok for me.

My `php.ini` doesn't include the last line with the port number or the apostrophe after the xdebug closing brace that you have.

```
[xDebug]
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

You shouldn't need the entire file path for your zend_extension considering that the extensions directory is already mapped for you.

I would double check that you've defined your `"php.debug.executablePath":` in vscode settings as well.

Here's what mine looks like after

1. Running `Listen for Xdebug` in vscode
2. Navigating to the file I used here at `http://localhost/info/index.php` in the browser

[image: Xdebug Running]

If making those changes still doesn't work, maybe double check that the breakpoint is actually reachable.

Comment: hi thanks for your help.
could you show me how your "php.debug.executablePath": look like.
That could be the problem.
Mine looks like this:
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.2.2",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "",
    "php.debug.executablePath": "",
    "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true

Comment: Now it works!
Normally i started xDebug with Control + F5.
That doesn´t not work anymore.
But if i click "Listen for XDebug" in the Debug section, as you recommended, it works.


If you understand the difference please tell me.

Comment: i have also changed the executablePath to this:
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
"php.debug.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",

Comment: Control + F5 is `Start without Debugging`   to start debugging instead it's just F5 alone @Nils